# jQuery - insert div after div

Tags: jquery, html, css, insert

I'm trying to add detail information after somebody clicks on an item on my site.

Here's my regular code (it is Bootstrap 3):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="portfolio_item">
                <!-- Info -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="portfolio_item">
                <!-- Info -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="portfolio_item">
                <!-- Info -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <!-- Same as above -->
    </div>
</div>
```

When somebody clicks a portfolio_item there should come a new `div` after the row the person clicked on.

```
$('.portfolio_item').click(function(){    
    var row = $(this).parent().parent();
    row.after('</div><div class="detailview">Detail Information</div><div class="container">');
}
```

As you can see, I break out of the container. That part doesn't work. When I log the source code of my page. This is what I see:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Same Row Info -->
    </div><div class="detailview">Detail Information</div><div class="container"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Same Row Info -->
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, it looks like it is added before the end of `.row` (like `append()`) instead of after it. When I insert it manually on the page, it works fine. Any idea how I should fix this?

**Solved:** Since I couldn't find a really good answer, here's how I solved it: I break out of the `.container` after every `.row` and don't add my `.detailview` after the `.row` but after the `.container`.

Comment: Your html show it is after .row  `<div class="row">
        <!-- Same Row Info -->
    </div><div class="detailview">`

Answer (score 0):

use  **[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

```
$('.portfolio_item').click(function(){    
    var row = $(this).closest(".row");
    row.after('<div class="detailview">Detail Information</div>');
}
```

Comment: This removes all of my `.row`

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking in markup, but the DOM isn't markup, it's *objects*.

If you want to insert a new `div` after the row the user is on, you're really close, just only specify what you want to add:

```
$('.portfolio_item').click(function(){    
    var row = $(this).parent().parent();
    row.after('<div class="detailview">Detail Information</div>');
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/IxoXadE/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/IxoXadE/1/edit)

I find it odd, though, that you want the details to be so far away from the item that was actually clicked (I assume it makes sense in the general context of your markup and styling).

Separately, I recommend using `closest(".row")` rather than `parent().parent()`.

---

In the comments you've said you want to actually split the container. You can do that, but to do it you have to create a new container, move the rows following the row in question into it, and then append it. Here's how:

```
$('.portfolio_item').click(function(){    
  var row = $(this).closest(".row");
  var followingRows = row.nextAll();
  var container = row.closest(".container");
  var newContainer = $('<div class="container"></div>');
  newContainer.insertAfter(container);
  $('<div class="detailview">Detail Information</div>').insertAfter(container);
  newContainer.append(followingRows);
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/IxoXadE/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/IxoXadE/2/edit)

Comment: But I got to break out of the container because `.detailview` should take up the whole width.

Comment: @yoeriboven: So you want two containers? That seems awkward.

Comment: Jup. Couldn't figure another way to do this.

Comment: @yoeriboven: I've added a way to do that, but I think I'd recommend stepping back and looking for another way to do this, possibly overlaying the details.

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = '</div><div class="detailview">Detail Information</div><div class="container">';

$('.portfolio_item').click(function(){    
    var row = $(this).closest(".row").after(html);
   console.log(row);
}
```

Comment: can you use this : $(this).parent().parent().append(html);